# Laravel - get related model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working with code that builds a query that starts with:

```
$products = \App\Product::where('id', '>', 0);
```

and then continues to add other related models to `$product`, depending on which arguments are provided.

I wanted to add a **related model** to the first line of code. But I'm doing something wrong apparently.

I try to add the "designer" relation by adding: `->get()->designer` , like this:

```
  return json_encode($products = \App\Product::where('id', '>', 0)
        ->get()->designer);
```

which gives the error: `Property [designer] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Switching the order doesn't work either: `->designer->get());`
(I get `Undefined property` )

My **Product** model has the method:

```
public function designer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Designer');
    }
```

And the Product table has a "`designer_id`" column ( it's a "belongsTo" relation so I guess the designer_id should be on the Product model).

The documentation says that : "we can access relationship methods as if they were defined as properties on the model":    `$comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments;`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $products = \App\Product::where('id', '>', 0)
           ->get()->designer;

this line of ur code is wrong; I guess ur relationship is one to many which means one designer has many products and one product belongs to one designer.

compared with the example of laravel documentation [comments and post], post has many comments and one comment belongs to one post.

when u execute this line : 
`$products = \App\Product::where('id', '>', 0)->get()`

laravel will return to u a collection of products objects witch means u can't get a designer by a collection of products because u have `belongsTo` relationship inside ur product model.

The solution for ur problem is to use `with` helper of eloquent like this :

```
$products = App\Product::with('designer')->where('id', '>', 0)->get();
```

in laravel community we name this

> Eager Loading technique to avoid n+1 requests.

u can find more information here [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

after that when u want to get designer attributs, u can access to them like this :

```
   foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->designer->name;
}
```

Comment: I was searching earlier for the "with" functiion but couldn't find it in the docs, so I thought it was a deprecated thing... so it is very vital in this case. Thanks!